# sqlite-net and Foreign keys

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android

I'm using this nice lightweight c# library to interface with sqlite dbs. The problem is that it doesnt support foreign keys. I Would like to know if there is any work around or it is a must to live with it.

Comment: sqlite-net (http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/)

Comment: Have a look at my version. It is very similar and has support for FKs : https://github.com/mattleibow/Mono.Data.Sqlite.Orm

Comment: It is based on sqlite-net, but has more features and relies on Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand instead of the custom SqliteCommand. Other than that, these are very similar libraries.

Comment: But now that I think about it, what do you mean by foreign keys. If you mean the creation of them, then my library does that. But if you mean the related entites. That is not the scope of either libraries. The library is very simple to be easy to map a database table to a c# entity. Not the relationships.

Comment: It's ok, I was refering to what your lib does